# Split single row to multiple according to a number

Tags: php, sql, select, row

Using the below select statement:

```
  select
      spec_sheet_color_comb.id,
      spec_sheet_color_comb.pairs*2 as total
  from
      spec_sheet_color_comb
  where 
        spec_sheet_color_comb.id_spec_sheet IN (4814)
```

And getting this result:

```
 id    total

79928   5
```

Now, I want to split this result according to the TOTAL quantity and get this result, 5 rows showing the ID:

Result

```
79928
79928
79928
79928
79928
```

It is really important, Thanks

Comment: Probably easier to do with php instead of SQL.

Comment: make another query `select spec_sheet_color_comb.id from spec_sheet_color_comb where  spec_sheet_color_comb.id=79928`

Comment: @jarlh how to do?

Comment: I don't know php, I'm a pure SQL guy!

Comment: @Sohel0415 what you mean? another query using the spec_sheet_color_comb.id=79928 will return only one row

Comment: What do you need this query for. Are you using it with php, c# or another programming language

Comment: If you're using PHP, you can do it like this:

$total = the number of rows from sql.
$id = the id returned from sql.

foreach ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
 echo $id . "<br />";
}

Comment: @Andam php language

Comment: Then just use your query result according to your total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a table having 2 columns id and total. (You can use your query instead of the table).

You need a collateral table (or view) with all the numbers `1..max_number_you_need`
e.g.

```
(select 1 as number
 union
 select 2 as number
 ...
 select 999 as number)
```

Then you can use the number source table joining your table you need to multiply rows

```
select id
from the_table t
     join (table with numbers) n on n.number<=t.total
```

UPDATE: an example

```
SELECT id
from (select 1 as id, 5 as total
      union
      select 2 as id, 3 as total) t
      join (select 1 as number
            union
            select 2 number
            union
            select 3 number
            union
            select 4 number
            union
            select 5 number) num on num.number<=t.total
order by id
```

Comment: Thank you, it was a good idea, I can get the result that I want to.